# Javascript Add Element To Array At Specific Index and Remover "Join" Separator

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, class, oop

I'm aware this question has been asked many times but I can't find the solution to my specific problem. I'm guessing that I need to refactor my code entirely but could use some guidance.

I am practicing OOP in Javascript. I would like to join an array and add an "and" conjunction before the last element. That way [1, 2, 3] ==> "1, 2, and 3".

I have included my code with comments below. As you will see, the current output I'm getting is "1, 2, and, 3". How can I get rid of the extra comma? Am I going about this the wrong way?

```js
class Person {
  constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
    this.name = {
      first: first,
      last: last,
    };
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.interests = interests;
  }

  greeting() {
    console.log(`Hi! I'm ${this.name.first} ${this.name.last}.`)
  }

  bio() {
    // store the index of the last element of the array in a variable called index
    let index = this.interests.length - 1;
    // store the conjunction for end of array
    let conjunction = " and"
    // insert the conjunction before last element in array
    this.interests.splice(index, 0, conjunction)
    // join the array into a string separated by commas
    let interestsString = this.interests.join(", ");
    console.log(interestsString);
  }
}

let person1 = new Person('test', 'test', '29', 'Male', ['skiing', 'cooking', 'gardening']);

console.log(person1.bio());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Intl.ListFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/ListFormat/ListFormat) to convert the list to a string while handling the separator, and the conjunction:

```js
const listFormatter = new Intl.ListFormat('en', { style: 'long', type: 'conjunction' });

class Person {
  constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
    this.name = {
      first: first,
      last: last,
    };
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.interests = interests;
  }

  greeting() {
    console.log(`Hi! I'm ${this.name.first} ${this.name.last}.`)
  }

  bio() {
    return listFormatter.format(this.interests);
  }
}

let person1 = new Person('test', 'test', '29', 'Male', ['skiing', 'cooking', 'gardening']);

console.log(person1.bio());
```

Another option is to use array manipulation - if the array contains only a single item, return that item. If the it contains more than one item, create a new array with all the original items, but the last, and the last item back after adding "and" to it. Join the array.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
    this.name = {
      first: first,
      last: last,
    };
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.interests = interests;
  }

  greeting() {
    console.log(`Hi! I'm ${this.name.first} ${this.name.last}.`)
  }

  bio() {
    return this.interests.length > 1 // if there are multiple items
      ?
      [
        ...this.interests.slice(0, -1), // get all items but the last
        `and ${this.interests.at(-1)}` // add the last item with "and"
      ].join(', ') // join
      :
      this.interests.at(0); // just take the single existing item
  }
}

let person1 = new Person('test', 'test', '29', 'Male', ['skiing', 'cooking', 'gardening']);

console.log(person1.bio());
```

Comment: Incredible answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing what you need.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
    this.name = {
      first: first,
      last: last,
    };
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.interests = interests;
  }

  greeting() {
    console.log(`Hi! I'm ${this.name.first} ${this.name.last}.`)
  }

  bio() {
    let interestsString = this.interests.join(', ').replace(/, ([^,]*)$/, ' and $1')
    console.log(interestsString);
  }
}

let person1 = new Person('test', 'test', '29', 'Male', ['skiing', 'cooking', 'gardening']);

console.log(person1.bio());
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I haven't learned much about Regex code yet so I'll do some research on how this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

when you used splice like this

```
 this.interests.splice(index, 0, conjunction)
```

you add element to the array , then the join function added another ","
better to just change the element it self and adding the and to it.

like this:

```
    let changeTo = conjunction + this.interests[index];
    this.interests.splice(index, 1, changeTo);
```

Comment: Clever workaround, thanks!